# how to trigger validation in React Hook Form in React Native Expo Web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-hook-form

How can I manually trigger form validation in React Hook Form, I would like to achieve effect of handleSubmit, but in keypress event handler and handleSubmit does not seem to work outside onPress. In the onPress handler, my code looks like so

```
  <Button
        color={enter ? COLORS.greys["gray-100"] : COLORS.TERTIARY}
        textColor={COLORS.FONT_COLOR}
        onPress={handleSubmit((data) => onSubmit(data))}
      >
        Enter
      </Button>
```

and when I click this button and fields are invalid the error message shows up, I want to do this same if user clicks Enter, but this code does not work

```
  const changeView = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      handleSubmit((data) => onSubmit(data));
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", changeView);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", changeView);
    };
  }, []);
```

I use getValues hook with onSubmit to make it work, but if the fields are invalid the form is not being validated

```
  const changeView = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      onSubmit(getValues());
    }
  };
```

How can I validate the form in the event listener's handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can form trigger function to validate the form manually

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger

```
form.trigger();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use fromik to form library   and yep library  to validation   this is usefull

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).